# Confusion matrix for FASTER R-CNN

Tags: performance, tensorflow, precision, confusion-matrix, faster-rcnn

I have trained my faster R-CNN model but I need precision, recall value. I have searched on google and  I have found something about it.

I have found this link(https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm
)  and I have implemented it like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq8z7.jpg)
Step1 :

python infer_detections.py --input_tfrecord_paths=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/test.record --output_tfrecord_path=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/inference_graph/detection_tfrecord --inference_graph=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/inference_graph/frozen_inference_graph.pb

but Step 2 : I have failed [ValueError: Flag --label_map is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBSPD.jpg)

python confusion_matrix.py--detections_record=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/inference_graph/detection_tfrecord.record--label_map=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt--
output_path=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/confusion_matrix.csv

https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm/issues/12

As you can see Picture 2 : There is an error. And Can you help me how can I fix that ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "confusion_matrix.py", line 142, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\Feyza\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\Feyza\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\Feyza\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "confusion_matrix.py", line 132, in main
    raise ValueError('Flag --{} is required'.format(flag_name))
ValueError: Flag --label_map is required
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add space before arguments such as --detections_record, --label_map. It should be

```
python confusion_matrix.py --detections_record=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/inference_graph/detection_tfrecord.record --label_map=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt --output_path=C:/tensorflow1msff/models/research/object_detection/confusion_matrix.csv
```